# jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-2.0.0.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist? How to resolve

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

At the time of deployment code, this problem occurred, which is unable to understand?

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiC10.jpg`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiC10.jpg%60) 
jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl
jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api
2.0.0


`

Comment: Have you done a build (i.e. `mvn clean package` or something like it)?

Comment: Yes, through manual I did.